# How to get a duration in format-"hh:mm" from minutes-integer with moments.js?

Tags: momentjs, duration

I have an integer value that's a count of minutes. I'm trying to use moments.js to display the minutes in hours and minutes even if the minutes exceed a day:

- 500  would yield "08:20"
- 1600 would yield "26:40"

This is what I have thus far:

```
function getDuration(value){

 return moment.utc().startOf('day').add(value, 'minutes').format('hh:mm')
}
```

The above code works the only problem is when the minute value exceeds 20 hours it starts from zero again.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can settle for a plain javascript implementation here is something for you:

```
function getDuration(n) {
    var hours = Math.floor(n / 60);
    var minutes = n % 60;
    return pad(hours) + ':' + pad(minutes);
}

function pad(s) {
    s = s + '';
    return s.length < 2 ? ('00' + s).substr(s.length, 2) : s;
}

document.write('see: ' + getDuration(1600));
document.write(', see: ' + getDuration(500));
document.write(', see: ' + getDuration(481));
document.write(', see: ' + getDuration(11600));
```